# What does this mean "->"?

Tags: c++, objective-c, operators

Ive almost only programmed in objective-c, for a couple of months ago I programmed a little in box2d and say this "->". Now what does that mean? its cant be objective-c it must be from c++ because box2d is c++, I one time saw someone using it in objective-c code and I just couldn't seem to understand what it did. Google doesn't support non-text characters so its impossible for me to google it since I don't know what it is.

Comment: You can probably guess it's an operator. That should be enough to find information on it.

Comment: "Google doesn't support non-text characters so its impossible for me to google it since I don't know what it is." - But it's an operator, and if you have a bit of imagination, you can deduce that it's an [arrow](http://google.com/search?q=arrow+operator+c). If you don't have any of imagination, that's [still not a problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=dash+greater+than+operator+c) - the characters this symbol is composed of have proper English names such as "dash" and "right angle bracket" or "greater than".

Comment: No, the symbol was inherited from C into both Objective-C and C++, with the same meaning in all three (if slightly expanded in C++, where it can be overloaded).

Comment: Why was this question downrated? This post was really helpful to me. Thanks for asking the question :).

Comment: @JPtheK9 Probably because of people thinking this is so basic everyone should know it and get irritated when someone dont :/ And because they thought I didnt google it which i totally tried!

Comment: Well this question popped up #1 in my Google search - I think that says something about their assumptions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The -> operator is shorthand for deferencing and then accessing a member.

Given

```
type *a;
```

`(*a).b` is equivalent to `a->b`

More information here, [en.wikipedia.org/wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Member_and_pointer_operators)