# Using * instead of -> operator in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, syntax-error

I created a very simple program of linked lists in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    struct Int{
        int num;
        struct Int *ptr;
    };
    typedef struct Int NODE;
    NODE *start;
    start = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    (*start).num = 100;
    (*start).ptr = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    (*start).(*ptr).num = 123;
    (*start).(*ptr).ptr = NULL;

}
```

When I replace the last two lines as :-

```
start -> ptr -> num = 123;
start -> ptr -> ptr = NULL;
```

The error solved.

The question is that why I can't use `(* start).` instead of `start  ->` .According to this answer ***[What does this mean "->"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251340/what-does-this-mean)***
both of them are same.

Comment: Because dot has to be followed by *member name*.

Comment: It would be helpful to include in the question what the "error" is.

Comment: **Which** error, you didn't have the compiler error in your code.

Answer (score 11):

you should write the last two lines as:

```
(*(*start).ptr).num = 123;
(*(*start).ptr).ptr = NULL;
```

because `(*ptr)` is not a member of `(*start)`, you should access `ptr` then dereference the whole expression.

Answer (score 4):

`*ptr` is not a member of `struct Int` - `ptr` is, so you can't have `*ptr` following the `.` operator.

If you absolutely have to use `*` and dereference your pointers, you need to treat the entire `(*strart).ptr` expression as a pointer:

```
(*(*start).ptr).num = 123;
(*(*start).ptr).ptr = NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

N3337 5.2.5/1,2

> A postﬁx expression followed by a dot . or an arrow ->, optionally followed by the keyword template (14.2),
>   and then followed by an **id-expression**, is a postﬁx expression.[...]
>
> In either case,
>   the id-expression shall name a **member of the class** or of one of its base classes.[...]

So *dot* has to be followed by name of the class member. You can't even write:

```
A a;
a.(some_member);//note the parentheses
```